# Msg 2627 Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database, duplicates, primary-key

trying to make a database for teams in a tv show here.
but when I try and insert data into `tblShowteam`
the following error made its appearance.

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 2
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__tblShowt__F693078C03317E3D'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblShowteam'.
```

**tables**

```
-- tabbellen aanmaken
create table tblShow(
setId       int,
Datum       date,
teams       int
primary key (setId));

create table tblShowteam(
SetId           int,
datum           date,
teams           int,
primary key (teams));


create table tblTeam(
TeamId      int,
Coach       varchar(35),
CoachId     int,
teams       int
primary key (CoachId));


-- participant table
create table tblDeelnemer(
DeelnemerId     int identity(1, 1),
DeelnemerV      varchar(35),
deelnemerT_V    varchar(10),
DeelnemerA      varchar(35),
CoachId         int,
datum_optreden  date
primary key (DeelnemerId));


--table for the public viewers
create table tblKijker(
Kijkerv         varchar(35),
KijkerT_V       varchar(10),
KijkerA         varchar(35),
Stoelnummer     int identity(1,3),
ShowId          int Not null,
Email           varchar(35)
primary key (Email));
```

my **inserts** would look like this:

```
insert into tblShowteam values (1, '2014-06-28', 1)
insert into tblShowteam values (2, '2014-06-05', 1)
insert into tblShowteam values (3, '2014-06-12', 1)
insert into tblShowteam values (4, '2014-06-19', 1)
insert into tblShowteam values (5, '2014-06-26', 1)
```

all other inserts (in diffrent tables) work like normal.

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: @Ben i have picked a random show out of the list of shows.
(will edit the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is here

```
   primary key (teams));
```

i guess you have to do it like that

```
  primary key (setId));
```

like that:

```
 create table tblShowteam(
 SetId           int,
 datum           date,
 teams           int,
 primary key (setId));
```

because you are inserting same teams `1` while you are using teams as `primary key` which means no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

your inserts:

```
insert into tblShowteam values (1, '2014-06-28', 1)
insert into tblShowteam values (2, '2014-06-05', 1)
...
```

DB translate it like this:

```
insert into tblShowteam (SetId, datum, teams) values (1, '2014-06-28', 1);
```

cause the third column is your primary key, you got this error.